# Finding a button with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to create a web application that automately republishes on a site for private sales.

Login and everything went well, but if I try to find and click the republish button it just wont work.
I've tried it with every locator, but the problem is that every button got an uniqe ID.
Example:

```
<button name="republish" type="button" data-testid="5484xxxxx-republish-button" class="Button__ButtonContainer-sc-3uxxxx-0 hxXxxX">Republish</button>
```

The last I've tried:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Republish')]")

for btn in buttons:
    btn.click()
```

But it also didnt work, same with `By.NAME`, `BY.TAG_NAME`

Comment: Is this sole button on whole page? If not how does other buttons (which you do not wish to click) looks like?

Comment: Yeah all of them got uniqe ID's
for example the ones were the buttons already got republished look like this:
<button name="upselling" type="button" data-testid="5768xxxx-upselling-button" class="Button__ButtonContainer-sc-3xxxxx-0 hxXxxX">Upgrade Item</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<button>` element looks to be dynamically generated so to click elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid$='republish-button'][name='republish']"))))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[starts-with(@class, 'Button__ButtonContainer') and contains(@data-testid, 'republish-button')][@name='republish' and text()='Republish']"))))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for that, its now able to locate the button. However, its not clickable because of a element over it, Ive tried to find solutions to ignore that element, but failed.

Comment: Error looks like this: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button name="republish" type="button" data-testid="576xxxxx-republish-button" class="Button__ButtonContainer-sc-3uxxxxx-0 xxxx">...</button> is not clickable at point (94, 16). Other element would receive the click: <img src="/xxxx/_next/static/assets/logo.xxxx.svg" alt="Logo" width="[object Object]" class="Image__StyledImage-sc-18kxxxx-0 xxxx">

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the result.